# How to properly call forget() in celery?

Tags: python, celery

I'm calling the following code, and want to implement forget()

```
for line in alldat:
    result = chain(get_url.s(line[:-1]),do_work.s(line[:-1])).apply_async()
    print('task submitted' + str(line[:-1]))
```

Comment: You can, for startes use `ignore_result=True` in your signatures. Try: `result = chain(get_url.s(line[:-1], ignore_result=True), do_work.s(line[:-1], ignore_result=True)).apply_async()`